# CreateJs Range slider function

Tags: createjs

Trying to create a range slider
similar to:

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/range_slider.html

it has to follow the mouse, so no onclick

and needs to output values between 0 (left side)
to 100 (right side) does anyone know the best way to go about this?

thanks

Comment: could really do with some pointers on this if anyone knows, how to constrain an object on the y axis for a slider
Using the below but the object arrowYou doesn't follow the mouse
it seems to go in the opposite direction

` exportRoot.game.arrowYou.addEventListener("mousedown",function (evt) {
var _this = evt.target
_this.parent.parent.addChild(_this)
 var offset = {x: _this.x - evt.stageX, y: _this.y - evt.stageY};
 
 evt.addEventListener("mousemove" , function(ev){
 // console.log(ev.stageX)
  
_this.x = ev.stageX + offset.x;
_this.y = ev.stageY + offset.y;

 
 })
`

Answer (score 0):

The EaselJS download actually includes a simple slider that is used by some of the examples. You could likely use that as a starting point and build on top of it.

https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/blob/master/_assets/js/Slider.js

The Transform.html and Filters_input.html samples in the examples directory use it if you'd like to see it in action.

http://www.createjs.com/demos/easeljs/transform